# Como usar o conteúdo do index em Python?

Tags: python

Tenho uma lista "list()" com N índices. Gostaria de saber como eu faço pra utilizar o conteúdo do índice e guardar ele em uma variável. Por exemplo:

> No índice [1] estiver a palavra "cachorro"

Como faço para guardar o conteúdo do índice dentro de uma variável?

> var = vaca

A minha ideia é fazer a variável ser "flutuante" de modo que eu possa fazer um "for" e somar o índice + 1 para que eu possa guardar na variável diversos valores enquanto rodo o programa.

Comment: Tente compartilhar seu código para outras pessoas entenderem melhor qual sua dúvida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para declarar uma lista você deve escrever:

```
MinhaLista = list()
```

Para adicionar um elemento nessa lista você deve utilizar a função **append()**

```
MinhaLista.append('vaca')
MinhaLista.append('cachorro')

>>MinhaLista
['vaca', 'cachorro']
```

Utilizando uma estrutura de repetição como o **for** você consegue adicionar quantos elementos precisar nessa lista.

Para acessar esses itens por índice:

```
>>MinhaLista[0]
vaca

>>MinhaLista[1]
cachorro
```

Você pode também utilizar o **for** para acessar os itens dessa lista:

```
for animal in MinhaLista:
    print(animal)

vaca
cachorro
```

Tendo esses índices, você pode alterar o item.

```
>>MinhaLista[1]
cachorro

MinhaLista[1] = 'passaro'

>>MinhaLista[1]
passaro
```

Fica como recomendação essa playlist com varias aulas sobre listas.
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHz_AreHm4dlKP6QQCekuIPky1CiwmdI6

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que parece seu problema pode ser solucionado da seguinte maneira:

```py
Lista = ["cachorro","vaca","gato"]
for palavra in Lista:
    temp = palavra
    #faça o que precisar com a variável temp
```

Assim independente do tamanho da lista você ira caminhar por toda ela.
Coloquei o `temp` para você não se confundir, mas é possível trabalhar direto com `palavra` que virou uma variável temporária até a próxima iteração do laço